# Pegar valores de uma planilha excel e exibir em uma pop-up

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou desenvolvendo uma planilha e estou com dificuldades ao começar a mexer com os macros/vba. Porém não consegui encontrar um tutorial que me mostrasse como fazer o que preciso.

Tenho uma tabela que diz:

```
nome | data1 | data2

Maria | 01-01 | 02-01

Marco |  02-01 | 03-01
```

Queria criar um botão chamado "Hoje" que quando clicado ele através da função hoje() verificaria na tabela se alguma das colunas de datas contém a data de hoje e mostraria os nomes em uma pop-up. Por exemplo, supondo que hoje é 02/01, ao clicar no botão seria aberto uma pop-up escrito: Maria e Marco.

Isso é possível no Excel? Muito obrigado.

Comment: Sim é possível! Pode usar `msgbox`para isso! Apenas gerar a lógica do código no vba para fazer essa verificação. Lembrando que datas com "01-01", usando um traço `-` não são padrão no Excel, mas se estiver usando formatação condicional, ok! Já fez algum código para gerar essa validação? Poderia postar?

Comment: @evis estou utilizando datas no padrão do excel, coloquei aqui só para exemplificar. No caso ainda não consegui fazer nada, olhei uns tutoriais de VBA mas tá muito complicado. Não criei a lógica pra gerar essa validação. Somente na minha cabeça mesmo. A lógica é: dentro de uma matriz de valores (colunas e linhas do excel) vou buscar a data de hoje. Após pegar a referência das linhas que tem a data de hoje, quero pegar a célula do nome da pessoa que tem a data correspondente. E ai exibir o nome das pessoas no msgbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde amigo, 
Não sei para qual finalidade você irá usar o método, mas uma forma simples de resolver o que você está tentando fazer é percorrer as duas colunas de datas que você criou e atribuir a uma string os nomes encontrados. Claro que, dependendo da sua regra de negócio, isso pode variar.
Segue exemplo do método:

```
Public Sub Pesquisa_Hoje()

Hoje = Format(Now, "DD/MM/YYYY")
Dim Achou As String
Dim Data As String

'Faz a busca na primeira coluna de datas
Fim = Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Fim
Data = Range("B" & i).Value

If Data = Hoje Then

    If Achou = "" Then
        Achou = Range("A" & i).Value
    Else
        Achou = Achou & ", " & Range("A" & i).Value
    End If

End If

Next

'Faz a busca novamente na segunda coluna de datas
Fim = Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Fim
Data = Range("C" & i).Value
If Data = Hoje Then

    If Achou = "" Then
        Achou = Range("A" & i).Value
    Else
        Achou = Achou & ", " & Range("A" & i).Value
    End If

End If

Next

'Mostra os nomes encontrados
If Achou <> "" Then

    MsgBox (Achou)

    Else

    MsgBox ("Nenhum nome encontrado!")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Obrigado pela disposição Luiz. Eu testei e ele não tá encontrando nomes. Mas vamos lá, no lugar de DD/MM/YYYY eu passei a data que eu queria, correto? Ou devo inserir em outro canto? Sou analfabeto em vba mesmo. Rodando o algoritmo tá, porque tá dando não encontrado.

Comment: Outra dúvida: o botão tá em uma planilha mas estou pesquisando em outra. A referência pode ser somente: Worksheets("OutraPlanilha") ou precisa de algum outro caractere, como o !

Comment: Luiz Henrique, funcionou! Muito obrigado, só um problema. Quando clico no botão não vai, mas quando clico no Play do VBA. Vai. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Vamos lá, primeira dúvida, nas suas colunas de data eu sugiro colocar o valor em formato de data normal (Ex: 13/11/2017), e na formatação da célula o formato que você quer exibir (Ex: 13-11), por que? A macro pega o value da célula que está passando, então o value sempre estará no formado padrão de acordo com o primeiro exemplo. Na outra dúvida, o exemplo que eu mandei, está trabalhando totalmente na sheet "Planilha1", caso seja necessário buscar em outra sheet você pode sim usar a referência Worksheets("OutraPlanilha") como exemplificou.

Comment: Que ótimo! Agora atribua a macro no botão que você criou, provavelmente funcionará!

Comment: Ótimo! Com as datas deu certo, mas ai eu atribui a Macro e ele não encontra =(

Comment: Lembrando que você deve salvar o documento como .xlsm e usar por garantia no botão o código da seguinte maneira:
    
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    call Pesquisa_Hoje
    End Sub

Comment: consegui fazer certinho, só funciona na planilha ativa mas ta valendo. Uma dúvida: se eu quisesse adicionar mais colunas, teria de copiar o código?

Comment: Boa tarde,
Sim, somente copiar a parte do for e adicionar pra ele percorrer na nova coluna que você incluir.

Answer (score 1):

### Código

Há várias maneiras de realizar um match nos valores de um arquivo Excel. (.Find, Match, Arrays, Dictionary, Collection, Autofilter, Loop, Excel Fórmula)

Se a planilha possui muitos dados os métodos que utilizam arrays são mais rápidos, porém o autofiltro também é rápido e mais fácil de entender. Portanto, este será usado. A interação entre o VBA e a planilha deve ser minimizado e esta [referência](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm) lida.

#### Declarações

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Worksheet de index 1 ou inserir o "NOME_entre_aspas"
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim j As Long, i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim VisibleRange As Range
Dim MyArray As Variant
ReDim MyArray(0 To 1000)
j = 0
```

#### Principal

```
Data = Format(Now, "dd-mm")
'Loop da Coluna 2 (B) até C(3)
With ws
    'Última Linha da coluna A
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To 3
    'AutoFiltro
        .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(1, i)).AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=Data
        'Cria range com as células visíveis após Filtrar
        On Error Resume Next
        Set VisibleRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not VisibleRange Is Nothing Then
        'Loop nas células visíveis após aplicação do AutoFiltro
        For Each Cell In VisibleRange
            MyArray(j) = Cell
            j = j + 1
        Next
        End If
        '"zera" o autofiltro, mostrando todos dados filtrados
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    Next i
    'Redimensiona Array para quantidade de elementos correto
    If j > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve MyArray(0 To j - 1)
    'Loop em cada elemento da Array para criar String
    For j = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        txt = txt & MyArray(j) & vbCrLf
    Next j
    MsgBox txt
    Else
    MsgBox "Nenhuma data encontrada."
    End If
End With
```

### Dados

Assumindo os valores da seguinte forma:

[image: Dados]

Caso esteja de outra, formatar na planilha ou no código.

### Resultado

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Ta dando erro nessa parte amigo: .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(1, i)).AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=Data

Comment: @JoãoNeto Quais as colunas utilizadas e o nome da planilha? A função `Cells` possui a seguinte sintaxe `Cells(LINHAS , COLUNAS)`. Também verifique o formato da data. Qual o código do erro?

Comment: Deu que não existia células. Colunas B e C e o nome da planilha é Pagamentos

Comment: Tente alterar de `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` para `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pagamentos")`. Caso não realize o filtro, verifique como as datas estão formatadas, no código está configurado para filtrar `Data = Format(Now, "dd-mm")`

Comment: Beleza, irei tentar. O código do colega acima tb funcionou. Deixa te perguntar. Existe uma forma de aumentar a capacidade do msgbox? Pq n tá cabendo tudo nele... São muitos registros.

Comment: Ela possui a capacidade de suportar 1024 caracteres. Você possui algumas opções para contornar o problema, uma delas é criar um arquivo .txt com estes dados, a outra é criar um Userform para mostrá-los e a outra é inserí-los em uma Planilha. Sugiro criar outra pergunta para esta questão com a opção que você achar melhor.