# Como setar os filtros em um PivotChart através de uma macro no Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Fiz um formulário VBA e queria que ao clicar em um botão as propriedades de filtro do gráfico dinâmico associado a uma tabela no Excel se alterassem.

Comment: Você precisa habilitar nas Ferramentas -> Referências do VBA no Powerpoint a opção `Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library` e criar um código que irá abrir o arquivo Excel desejado e realizar estas alterações com código Excel VBA. Ou se for um código VBA no Excel, você precisa escolher qual o gráfico (se houver mais de um) e realizar as alterações dos parâmetros.

Comment: Quais propriedades você deseja alterar? E como? Com Formulário em que o usuário digita os parâmetros ou na célula do Excel?

Comment: Um formulário que eu digite os parâmetros como data inicio e data fim, ou um código de produto.

Comment: Você pode usar o autofiltro `.Autofilter` para filtrar os dados da tabela. No começo [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/255058/75104) há um exemplo de como usar o autofiltro no código para um valor fixo. No exemplo `Data`, este pode ser linkado com um campo de texto no formulário `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por que você não usa segmentação de dados para a criação de Dashboards?

Com segmentação de dados, você pode conectar e filtrar facilmente várias tabelas e gráficos dinâmicos sem a necessidade de usar VBA:

[image]